# Better solution for removing duplicates from a Python list

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have two functions to remove duplicates from a list:

```
def solution1(a: List):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in a:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            result.append(item)
    return result

def solution2(a: List):
    result = []
    for item in a:
        if item not in result:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

I got `solution1` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710045/time-and-space-complexity-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list). It's time and space complexities are `O(n)`.

I believe `solution2` also has a space complexity of `O(n)`. What is the time complexity? The `for` loop is `O(n)` but I'm not sure about the `in` statement because the length of `result` isn't as big as the input `a`. Is it also just `O(n)`?

Lastly, if both solutions have the same time and space complexities, is either considered "better"? Which should I use in an interview?

It looks like `solution1` uses more space (maybe `O(2n)` but I know we're supposed to leave off the constant in front) and completes in shorter time (testing for set membership is faster than testing for list membership).

Comment: Consider the case where the input list is all unique.  There's no question that solution2 will be O(n^2) in time for that case.

Comment: btw There is no O(2n); you're mixing concepts. Average number of computations can be expressed as 2n, but but asymptotic analysis is expressed as just the variable: O(n), O(n^2), O(lg n).

Comment: why dont you just convert the list into a set and back to a list. It will remove duplicates.

Comment: Even though `result` is smaller than `a`, lookups in `result` still grow linearly with `n`, therefore `solution2` as a whole is O(n^2). If you want the fastest solution and show that you understand how to leverage Python's strengths: `result = list(set(a))` is all you need (assuming you don't care about order) - otherwise, `solution1` is OK.

Comment: `O(2N)` *is* `O(N)`. In any case, your second solution is quadratic time, your first solution is linear time. Generally, the set-based solution is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that `solution1` space complexity is `O(2n)` but it can be approximated to `O(n)` which is roughly the same as `solution2` in terms of space.

However, in terms of time efficiency, `solution1` should be better than `solution2` due to the lookup time for `set` data structure (`if item not in seen:`) is roughly `O(1)` while lookup time for regular python list (`if item not in result:`) is `O(n)`. Therefore, It would be better if you use `solution1` in an interview

You can see here for more information on time complexity of Python's data structure
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Saying something uses more space "O(2N)" vs "O(N)" fundamentally misuses big-oh notation, which by definition is concerned with asymptotic behavior that is "at most a positive constant multiple" of some function. IOW O(2N) *is* O(N)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right. I've updated my answer according to your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The second answer is actually greater than O(n) - it's more like O(n^2). This is because the time complexity of `if item not in result` depends on the number of elements in the list `result` i.e. it's `O(n)`. See this answer for an explanation: [Complexity of *in* operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884177/complexity-of-in-operator-in-python).

This is why the first answer is better: it uses a `set` or a `dictionary`, whose time complexity is (at best) constant time.

Comment: As 'm' grows linearly with 'n', "O(nm)" is just a confusing way of saying O(n^2) here.

Answer (score 1):

## using set to remove duplicates

Here's one way to do it:

```
dups = [10,20,30,40,50,10,20,50,60,80,90]
print (dups)
remove_dups = list(set(dups))
print(remove_dups)
```

The output will look like this:

Original list:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 50, 60, 80, 90]
```

Dups removed list:

```
[40, 10, 80, 50, 20, 90, 60, 30]
```

## using minimal look back to remove dups

I also think this may reduce the lookup and be faster than a full scan of the list while preserving the order.

```
[a for i,a in enumerate (x) if a not in x[:i]]
```

Output is as follows:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 80, 90]
```

Comment: Your solution is not guaranteed to preserve order though - the OP's solution is.

Comment: @Grismar depends on the version of Python.  The latest couple will preserve insertion order of dictionaries and sets.

Comment: What are the space and time complexities here? Looks like `O(1)` space and `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: @MarkRansom no, `set` objects do not preserve order in any Python version

Comment: @JohnnyMetz no, it's O(N) space and O(N) time. It's essentially the same as your first solution but it doesn't maintain order

Comment: If the order needed to be preserved, this wouldn't work. But if not, I think this would be the best solution, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: @JohnnyMetz, agree. If the order is not an issue, using set will be the best option. Also, I added another option where we look back only the items we have iterated thru. that way the lookup is faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga interesting.  I thought the insertion order guarantee would hold for both dictionaries and sets, but evidently it's only for dictionaries.  I wonder why the difference?

Comment: @MarkRansom because `set` objects are not implemented as `dict` objects with empty values. There's a *lot* going on with Python `dict` objects. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8) a pretty good discussion on the current state of the dict, by one of its maintainers.

Comment: `[a for i,a in enumerate (x) if a not in x[:i]]` nah, `x[:i]` creates a copy, so you are losing any efficiency gains by slicing it. Botton line, if you want to do this efficiently, use a `set`, don't use membership testing in a list in a loop