# What is under the hood when inserting an item to a specific index in a Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, time-complexity

I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139870/3552975) that the fastest method to insert an item at an index would be like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[2:2] = ["12345"]
```

But I don't know why. And I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073627/3552975) that the complexity would never be O(1).

I tried the following and verified the statement that it should be larger than O(1).

```
python3 -m timeit --setup="a = list(range(1000))" "a[500:500] = [3]"
50000 loops, best of 5: 3.89 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit --setup="a = list(range(100000))" "a[500:500] = [3]"
10000 loops, best of 5: 20.1 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit --setup="a = list(range(1000000))" "a[500:500] = [3]"
1000 loops, best of 5: 340 usec per loop
```

I thought that we can [pinpoint the address/pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717961/3552975) in O(1) and then we only need to direct that address to the new item, and it would be O(1). I thought I should be wrong since that would scoot over the addresses of the items on the right side.

I tried to see what is `a[2:2]` but it turns out to be just an empty list. I thought it would be possible to separate the indexing and the assignment. I mean if we can first get the pointer of a particular index and then make it point to a new item?

```
In [14]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [15]: b = a[2:2]
In [16]: b = ["12345"]
In [17]: b
Out[17]: ['12345']
In [18]: a
Out[18]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [19]: a[2:2] = ["12345"]
In [20]: a
Out[20]: [1, 2, '12345', 3, 4, 5]
```

In the code above I want to get the pointer by `b=a[2:2]` and then redirect that to a new item `"12345"` by `b = ["12345"]`.

What's going on under the hood? Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you find when you tried to measure the time of an insert operation for different sizes of lists?

Comment: This answer gives explanations and links to further reading material about what's going on under the hood: [How is Python's List Implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented)

Comment: That first question you link, I cannot reproduce the different timings. It reports 8x (!) slower for `list.insert` vs. slice assignment. This seems more than unrealistic (even for older versions of Python) and I obtain the same performance for Python 3.8. Whether or not this operation is O(1) depends on the implementation of the list type. For most implementations it won't be O(1) though.

Comment: on average, the time complexity for insertion within a `list` is `O(1)` but within the *worst case* it can be complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073665/) to one of the questions you have linked to it says that the insert operation has linear time complexity. Does that not answer your question?

Comment: @FishingCode Where did you find that O(1)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050808/does-insert-at-the-end-of-a-list-have-o1-time-complexity.

Comment: @FishingCode Note that it says *at the end*.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You are right. I tried and find that the time increases as the list size increases.

Answer (score 1):

This `a[2:2] = [123]`
means that the empty list that was from the second index and upto the second index is being assigned to a non empty list which will henceforth fill that space.

There are other ways to insert elements in list. One of the most common and direct way is `list.insert(index, element)`.

Comment: How can I get the pointer of that empty list? Can I do that in another way? Separating the indexing and the assigning?

Comment: I think what I mean is why or how we can insert an item by filling an empty space? What is the empty space? Does it have an address?

Comment: Can we fill an empty space by `[] = [3, 4]`? I don't think it is the same as `a[2:2] = [4]`, is it?

Comment: you should think of it like this: `b = [], b = [3,4]`. here you are filling that empty space with another list right. this is what you are doing with `a[2:2] = [4]`,

Answer (score 0):

This question requires some basic understanding of how python works. Lets start with assignment of value to a variable.
In python the values are given a memory location and variables are just tags to that location. When you change the value of the variable the value in that memory location is not changed, rather a new memory is assigned to the new value and the tag not points to the new memory. When a memory has not tags pointing to it, it is garbage collected.E.g.

```
a = 5
b = a
b = 6
print(a, b)
```

this will give you output 5 6. a is still 5 and b is now 6.

Now let's talk about slicing operation in a list in python. The simplest definition is, ar[k:m] gives list starting from index k to m, m not including.

Hence ar[n:n] would be an empty list **starting** at n.(Python is awesome that way). Now when this statement ar[k:m] is on the left side of an assignment this is reference to the list in that range. E.g.

```
ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
ar[1:2] = [13]
```

this will take the list starting at index 1 till 2 not including index 2, i.e. [1] and replace it with a list [13]. Thus, ar now becomes [0,13,2,3,4,5,6]

now if we do

```
ar[2:5] = [3]
```

then ar becomes [0,13,3,5,6]

Now comes the funs part. ar[2:2] is a list starting at index 2 and having no element thus an assignment will not change any existing entry, but rather create a list starting at index 2:

ar[2:2] = [1,2,3]

ar becomes [0,13,1,2,3,3,5,6]

Now, a bit confusing part. When the slicing operating is at the right side of assignment operator then a copy of the list is created and assigned to the variable on the left.

```
b = ar[2:4]
```

b becomes [1,2]

since b is a copy of ar any change you do to b will not effect ar.

Answer (score 0):

Beware: the first referenced question was about producing a modified version of a list *without changing the original*.

Using insert or slice notation for adding one single element is more or less the same thing. Slice notation is better is you insert a sublist, and the longer the sublist, the more difference.

As under the hood a Python list is a dynamic sized array (what C++ calls a vector, or Java an ArrayList), inserting something in the list requires:

- optionnaly allocate a new array and copy the original there if the reserved (and unused) size is not enough for the additional content
- unless you add at the end, move everything starting at the insertion index to the end of the array
- put the new content in the free place

That is the reason why:

- adding an element to the end of the array is O(1)
- inserting an element at the beginning of the array is O(n) - inserting it at a random position averages to n/2 which is still O(n)
- inserting m elements in an array with one single slice operation is O(n)
- inserting m elements in an array with m insert operations is O(n*m)

Any of those operations can get a significant overhead if it requires a new allocation.