# Iterables / generators with specified length

Tags: python, iterator, generator, iterable

Iterable objects are those that implement `__iter__` function, which returns an iterator object, i.e. and object providing the functions `__iter__` and `__next__` and behaving correctly. Usually the size of the iterable object is not known beforehand, and iterable object is not expected to know how long the iteration will last; however, there are some cases in which knowing the length of the iterable is valuable, for example, when creating an array. `list(x for x in range(1000000))`, for example, creates an initial array of small size, copies it after it is full, and repeats for many times as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045038/6087087). Of course, it is not that important in this example, but it explains the point.

Is there a protocol in use for those iterable objects who know their length beforehand? That is, is there a protocol extending [Sized and Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) but not [Collection or Reversible](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)? It seems like there is no such protocol in language features, is there such a protocol for well-known third-party libraries? How this discussion relates to generators?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384570/whats-the-shortest-way-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-generator-iterator

Comment: @PM77-1 I do not want to know the length of an arbitrary generator. I am coding the generator and I know what it's size will be. I want `len(generator)` to return that number.

Comment: Please explain what is "verbose" about that solution.  You're defining a new class; you inherit from an existing class, or provide your own (trivial) iterator.  Either way, you override the inherited (or default) `len` function.

Comment: @Prune Creating a class for a simple iteration procedure is verbose in the literal sense. There are too much words that complicate the code. Compare that with the syntax of a generator.

Comment: You asked only whether it was _possible_…

Comment: Are you comparing your new class with the syntax of *instantiating* a generator?  Why would you expect those to be on the same order?  Compare instead to the generator *definition* -- better yet, to any other single-method class extension.

Comment: @Prune You are totally right. I have improved the question thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about something like `__length_hint__`. Excerpts from [PEP 424 – A method for exposing a length hint](https://peps.python.org/pep-0424/):

> CPython currently defines a `__length_hint__` method on several types, such as various iterators. This method is then used by various other functions (such as `list`) to presize lists based on the estimate returned by `__length_hint__`. Types which are not sized, and thus should not define `__len__`, can then define `__length_hint__`, to allow estimating or computing a size (such as many iterators).

> Being able to pre-allocate lists based on the expected size, as estimated by `__length_hint__`, can be a significant optimization. CPython has been observed to run some code faster than PyPy, purely because of this optimization being present.

For example, `range` iterators support this ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7NEwVYhsyS1SKMoMS89VcPQwMBAU5OroCgzr0Qjs0QvPj4nNS@9JCM@AygQH68BlMtLrQBJ4VX0/z8A)):

```
it = iter(range(1000))
print(it.__length_hint__())     # prints 1000
next(it)
print(it.__length_hint__())     # prints 999
```

And `list` iterators even take list length changes into account ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1HBViHaLz8vNVZBS8HQgCuzBCiQWZJapJGoyVVQlJlXopFZohcfn5Oal16SEZ8BFIiP19DU5MpLrQBJ4VeUqFeQX6BBSE1iQUFqXooGyBV4lf7/DwA)):

```
a = [None] * 10
it = iter(a)
print(it.__length_hint__())     # prints 10
next(it)
print(it.__length_hint__())     # prints 9
a.pop()
print(it.__length_hint__())     # prints 8
a.append(None)
print(it.__length_hint__())     # prints 9
```

Generator iterators don't support it, but you can support it in other iterators you write. Here's a demo iterator that...

- Produces 10,000 elements.
- Hints at having 5,000 elements.
- After every 1,000 elements it shows the memory size of the list being built.

```
import gc

beacon = object()

class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 10_000
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __length_hint__(self):
        print('__length_hint__ called')
        return 5_000
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.n -= 1
        if self.n % 1_000 == 0:
            for obj in gc.get_objects():
                if isinstance(obj, list) and obj and obj[0] is beacon:
                    print(obj.__sizeof__())
        return beacon

list(MyIterator())
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBSsQwEIbveYq5yCagJYsIIuwDePDkUSRk02l3pE5KEsH15WvSLnZtm0vI8OWbyZ/@nE6e7x/7MAz02fuQoHVCHNE6z3AAf/xAl6QSwnU2Rng5PycMNvnwJCCvGhswhpiSMTJi16ipXlY5VkWy10Zrfc1nx5oPmL4Cj9eu2A65TSdzIt5o0YdclrsFBc52HdY7tVQ/LOZg/N6QUvM3@gH0XB9FliLCa/L9lAN5Xr73Lj94w3UD@9J9w9n4UHIG4px91WIyU@pRqv/gRUiROCbLDmUGb6GjmBRYrkfLZX/T7xmE6SPXmjm8zFbGRPpB3@Qs1Cq0SSFEaSPn/8/kMPwC)):

```
__length_hint__ called
45088
45088
45088
45088
45088
50776
57168
64360
72456
81560
```

We see that `list` asks for a length hint and from the start pre-allocates enough memory for 5,000 references of 8 bytes each, plus 12.5% overallocation. After the first 5,000 elements, it doesn't ask for length hints anymore, and keeps increasing its size bit by bit.

If my `__length_hint__` instead accurately returns 10,000, then `list` instead pre-allocates `90088` bytes and that remains until the end.

Comment: Indeed! I compared the running times of converting two iterators of the same length, 10^8, to lists, where one of them supports __len__. It was around %10 faster.

Comment: @FıratKıyak Did you mean to say `len` or did you mean `length_hint`? Can you share your code? Tried it myself now but I'm actually having trouble producing any significant speed difference. I'm trying this with Python code, which is just too slow in comparison and dominates the runtime.

Comment: I run "%timeit list(X(10**8))" for 3 distinct classes for X. Every one of them is an iterator sharing the same code for __iter__, __next__, and __init__ which imitate the range iterator. One of them implements __len__ and gives the number of remaining terms in the iteration. Another one does the same, but it does that with __length_hint__ method instead of __len__. The other one does not implement any of the two functions. Both functions implementing a length function outperformed the one didn't by running about %5-%10 faster. Comment is too small for sharing the code.

Comment: @FıratKıyak That sounds like what I'm doing. Can you put it for example on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##1ZLBasMwDIbvfgod7RLKusAYhTzADnsG47ZKYxbLRlFgffrMicuWEdb7dLP0/b9k2ekmXaT6NfE0tRwDiA/oBXxIkQUYEzpRiqCBw9Nu96LUuXfDAO@3N0F2EvlwVJDjgi1Y68mLtXrAvjUlP8d83A9x5DNmH5@Fmh1dUZMxe2sJP7No7ZKJrQujjEyL2Yot4gfsvbE229Gf/83oP6Ie6U8N/eau0tnOkzzgVRsZLHiCcqv6Ds3pj2VbubR662q7vTkk7yZ40uW76N6F08UdofeD6MVGG1MBjeGE3GSTwjW1Md8WifOkWqrSdl6tC2htAUrRTNMX) or ideone.com or some pastebin?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7gFpZrCe

Comment: @FıratKıyak Thanks. I tried that on Google Colab, there it does seem to make a 5% difference. And with mine from my previous comment I see about a 10% difference there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I now understand your question, you're still trying to combine two concepts that don't combine in quite this way.  `generator` is a subclass of `iterator`; it's a process.  `len` applies to data objects -- in particular, to the *iterable* object, as opposed to the *iterator* that traverses the object.

Therefore, a generator doesn't really have a length of its own.  It returns a sequence of values, and that sequence has a length (when the generator finishes).  Can you describe the concept you have of "generator with length" -- if it differs from what I just described?

If you keep that distinction in mind, then yes, you can implement `__len__` as an extension to your class.  You can add anything you like -- say, a `sqrt` function (See Conway's surreal numbers for details).

Comment: Even though there is a distinction between generator function and generator iterator: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator , you are right either way. The generators are not iterable. I have realized generators obscure the question I am asking, and I edited the question greatly, hoping that what I am asking is now clear.