# What would the Big O notation be for alphabetically sorting each element in a nested list comprehension

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, big-o

```py
# find all possible sorted substrings of s
substr = ["".join(sorted(s[i: j])) 
                for i in range(len(s)) 
                    for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]
```

I know the `sorted()` method is O(nlog(n)), and the finding of all possible substrings is O(n^2). However, the `.join()` is what is throwing me off. `sorted()` returns a list and `.join()` iterates over each element in the list to append it to a string. So it should be a linear operation.

Would my substring sorter therefore be O(n^2) for the nested loop * O(nlogn) for sorting each result * O(n) for joining? Ergo O(n^4logn)??

If so, would breaking up the operations make this more efficient? I had another implementation where I move the sorting of the substrings to a second list comprehension

```py
substr = [s[i: j] for i in range(len(s)) 
                for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1)]

sortedSubstr = ["".join(sorted(s)) for s in substr]
```

This would make it the O(n^2) list comprehension first + O(n)*O(nlogn) for the second list comprehension

Making the overall program now O(n^2logn)

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: You only join once, and the cost of the join is the sum of the lengths of its input. So why would you.*multiply* by O(n)? The cost of the join is the sum of the lengths of all substrings, plus the sum of the costs of creating each string to be joined.

Comment: Because each .join() is happening for each substring in the list. Its not doing it just once, it’s for each iteration of the comprehension

Comment: that doesn't change the sum of the length of the arguments, though. The sum is the same whether done all at once or divided into a bunch of calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of analysis, let's replace the comprehensions with their equivalent loops as described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Your first approach becomes

```py
substr = []
for i in range(len(s)): # O(n)
    for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1): # O(n)
        substr.append("".join(sorted(s[i: j]))) # O(n*logn)

# Overall O(n^3 * logn)
```

Note that `substr.append("".join(sorted(s[i: j])))` is not multiplicative, rather it is a sequential combination of the following operations (no actual assignments happen)

```py
temp = s[i:j] # O(j-i), which worst case we can take O(n)
sorted_temp = sorted(temp) # O(n*logn)
joined_temp = "".join(sorted_temp) # O(n)
substr.append(joined_temp) # amortized O(1)

# Overall O(n*logn)
```

Now in the second approach the code becomes

```py
substr = []
for i in range(len(s)): # O(n)
    for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1): # O(n)
        substr.append(s[i:j]) # O(n) for the slice
# first loop: O(n^3)

sortedSubstr = []
for s in substr: # O(n^2), we have appended n^2 times in the first loop
    sortedSubstr.append("".join(sorted(s))) # O(n*logn)
# second loop: O(n^3 * logn)

# Overall O(n^3 * logn)
```

So as you can see, they should be the same time complexity. I almost missed `substr` length being `n^2` rather than `n`, so that might be a pitfall.

References for time complexity of various operations:

1. [Time complexity of string slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180377/time-complexity-of-string-slice)
2. [Why is the time complexity of python's list.append() method O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044883/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-pythons-list-append-method-o1)

Answer (score 1):

For the first algorithm time complexity is `O(n^3*log(n))`, because after two loop you are not making a `join` for each atomic action in `sorted`. You separately sort and join. So `O(n) + O(n*log(n)) = O(n*log(n))`, which multiplied by `O(n^2)` (nested loops) gives us `O(n^3*log(n))`.

About the second algorithm.

- Calculation of `substr` gives us `O(n^3)`: same `O(n^2)` for nested loops multiplied by `O(n)` for slicing `s`.
- Note that `len(substr)` is `O(n^2)` — for each `(i, j)` from nested loops.
- Calculation of `sortedSubstr` gives us `O(n^3*log(n))`: for each element of `substr` (whose count is `O(n^2)`) we call `sorted`. Each element's `len` is `O(n)`, so `sorted(s)` gives us `O(n*log(n))`. So, samely, `O(n^2) * O(n*log(n)) = O(n^3*log(n))`.
- Calculation of `substr` (`O(n^3)`) plus calculation of `sortedSubstr` (`O(n^3*log(n))`) yields `O(n^3*log(n))`.

So the same `O(n^3*log(n))` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

In this expression:

```
"".join(sorted(s[i: j]))
```

the O(n) `join` is negligible, because you're doing it once, after you've done the O(nlogn) `sort`.

`O(nlogn + n)` = `O((n+1)logn)` = `O(nlogn)`

Doing that sort n^2 times gets you to `O(n^3 logn)`, regardless of whether/when you do the `join`.

Comment: Yes but the .join() occurs for each element in the list, as well as the O(nlogn) occurs for each iteration of the n^2 loop.

Comment: Yes; I was just addressing the `join` specifically as not being relevant since that was the specific thing OP said they were hung up on.  I.e. `join(sorted(...))` will always have the same time complexity as `sorted(...)`, because it's just adding an O(n) operation to an O(nlogn) operation.  Doing that in an n^2 loop means overall it's `n^2 * nlogn`, or `n^3 logn`.

Comment: What about the second solution I provided? Would that not overall just be O(nlogn) for the sort * O(n) iterating over the second list? O(n^2logn) > O(n^2) which the n^2 is from the first nested list comprehension

Comment: No, because the second list isn't `n` items, it's `n^2` items.  (Or technically it's `n^2/2` items or however the combinatorics works out, but when we're talking about big-O it's the same thing.)

Comment: Ohhhh true!! I was thinking in terms of it being linear and not taking into account the fact that the list is now n^2 bigger