# What is the time complexity for appending an element to a list?

Tags: python, list, append, time-complexity

What is the time complexity for appending an element to a list in Python?

Comment: Did you try to use a search engine to find an answer for this? What happened when you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the time complexity of python's list.append() method O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044883/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-pythons-list-append-method-o1)

Answer (score 1):

According [official python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) adding an element to list has `O(1)` time complexity.

And if you want to copy a list it takes `O(n)`, where `n` is a list size.