# What is the average and worst case time complexity of appending "n" elements one by one in an empty Python list?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

According to my understanding, Python lists use dynamic array as the underlying data structure. Therefore, appending an element when allocated memory is not full should take `O(1)` time, but when the allocated memory is full, it would allocate almost double the size of the current array in memory then create a copy of the array and append the element, which should take `O(n)` time where `n` is the size of the current array.

I came across [Why is the time complexity of Python's list.append() method O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044883/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-pythons-list-append-method-o1) which discusses time complexity of appending a single element.

But, what would be the time complexity if I append `n` elements one by one in an empty Python list?

Answer (score 1):

When you're appending "n" elements one by one to an empty Python list, the overall time complexity is dominated by the sum of these individual append operations.

Here’s a breakdown of such situations:

- **Average Case**: The average case time complexity is O(1) for each append operation due to the dynamic array implementation, which allows for fast appends most of the time. Therefore, for "n" appends, the average case time complexity is O(n).
- **Worst Case**: The worst-case scenario occurs when each append operation triggers a memory reallocation and copying of all existing elements. However, due to the geometric (or sometimes exponential) progression of the memory allocation sizes, the reallocations become less frequent as the number of elements in the list grows. This results in an amortized time complexity of O(1) for each append operation, even in the worst case. Therefore, for "n" appends, the worst case time complexity is still O(n).

The key here is the concept of **amortization**, which spreads out the occasional O(n) cost of a single append operation over a series of O(1) append operations, resulting in an amortized cost of O(1) per append operation. Hence, the total time complexity for appending "n" elements one by one is O(n), both in the average and worst case (same as creating list of length n).

Comment: What's the difference between geometric and  exponential, and when does each occur?